# How to access a wordpress plugin page or add posts without doing it from the Wordpress dashboard?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am a creating a website on WordPress that uses a plunging called H5P which allows the creation of interactive content. as in the picture below. However the creation of the content is currently only possible from the dashboard.
I would like to allow my website guests to use the plugin to create content but from a separate page and without letting them access or use the WordPress dashboard. In other words, I just want to show the users the section in green in the picture.
Similarly, Is there any way to allow the guests to create posts also without going from the dashboard? such as another page that the same fields to create a post but to be visited without going through WordPress dashboard?

[image]

Thanks a lot for any help you may provide

Comment: Is this an inquiry whether this is possible with what the plugin has in stock or a question? Then no. Is this possible with proper amount of coding? Then yes.

Answer (score 0):

For creating post/custom post content from the front-end, one solution is to use the fol owing popular plugin and extensions,

[Contact Form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) plugin - a popular and simple approach to form designs in WordPress.

[Smart Grid-layout Design for CF7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/) extension plugin - this allows you to design and build multi-column and multi-row grid layout forms to make your form more compact.
To see how this plugin can help you design better forms, see this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0DYxRpWc_F0) on how to design a 2-column form layout.
This plugin extension was designed to fix the flaws of the CF7 plugin as well as improve its functionality, and as a result does a great many things.  Once you install the plugin it adds a a tutorial section in admin dashbaord with a list of all the online tutorials available to learn how to use it.

[Post My CF7 Form](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-my-contact-form-7/) extension - allows you to map a CF7 form to a post or a custom post in the back-end.
To map a form to an existing post, please follow this online [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j3DP7TCbUlM&list=PLblJwjs_dFBtQzwPMoMFf-vsXkhuKHKhV&index=3).
To map a form to a custom post type, please follow this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BcIkJbBclKE&lc=Ugx2K-zGaasb3o0zGbp4AaABAg).
The plugin also allows you to map dropdown lists to taxonomies, files to post thumbnails, and many more options.  To understand how to do this, see this [playlist of tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLblJwjs_dFBtQzwPMoMFf-vsXkhuKHKhV).